# How to build web forum in android app

Tags: android, forum, building

I am studying android app.

and I am thinking to study about building web forum in my app. (it's like forum in open feints).

Is there any resource that i can reference for building web forum in my app ?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean "forum" of "form" in your title?

Answer (score 5):

I'm unsure what you mean by 'webforum' if you want to embed a webforum in your app use webkit: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

If you want to make a forum native to Android break it down into pieces. You're going to need to store the data, check out SQLite and other storage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You'll need a way for users to post things, check out custom dialogs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

You'll need to build your forum it's self so look at UI elements. This is really a difficult question to answer accurately since there's very little information. Hopefully this is of some help.

**EDIT:** Just noticed you say both "forum" and "form" if you mean form then custom dialogs should be sufficient. You can embed UI elements for input like EditText in them.

Comment: i mean " forum". i am sorry .. my bad.

Comment: Okay, does my response answer your question or?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add Geolocation & Search & geolocated search you can use mobyview platform.
All these options are available and will be very usefull for you.

Diane